# How can i show my csv data file in jupyter notebook using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a big data csv dataset. I need to read it on jupyter-notebook using pyspark. My data is about 4+ million records (540000 rows and 7 columns.) What can i do so i can show all my dataset printed?

I tried to use pandas dataframe, but it does show error as in the attached screenshot, then i tried to change the encoding type it gives SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing. Can you please help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the last screenshot I think you are missing the way files are reading in python by using the handler `with`. If your data is in a json file your can read it as follows:

```
with open('data_file.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
```

Note that it is `'data_file.json'` and not `data_file.json`. The same logis holds for the csv example

If it is in a csv file, tha's pretty straigtforward:

```
file = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv')
```

Try removing the encoding parameter in your csv reading step
I would not recommend to use a notebook for reading such a huge file even if you are using pyspark for that. Consider using a portion of that file for visualized in a notebook and then switch to another platform.

Hope it helps